# How can I test functions that are provided by context using jest and react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a `<UserProvider />` component that provides context which has a `login` method in its value. In my test I want to check if that method has been called. How can I check to make sure this method is being called in my test if it comes from context? I've tried using the [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) and [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) methods but I can't get them to work.

Here's my `UserProvider` component which provides the context.

```
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react'

const UserContext = createContext()

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const login = user => setUser(user)

  return <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, login }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
}

const useUser = () => useContext(UserContext)

export { UserProvider, useUser }
```

Here's my `Login` component using the context from `UserProvider` (via `useUser`)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useUser } from './UserProvider'

function Login() {
  const { login } = useUser()

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    // I need to make sure this method is being called in my test.
    login({ name: 'John Doe' })
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <button>Login</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Here's my `Login` test

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import Login from './Login'
import { UserProvider, useUser } from './UserProvider'

// Is this correct?
jest.mock('./UserProvider', () => ({
  useUser: jest.fn(() => ({
    login: jest.fn()
  }))
}))

it('should log a user in', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(
    <UserProvider>
      <Login />
    </UserProvider>
  )

  const submitButton = getByText(/login/i)
  fireEvent.click(submitButton)

  // How can I make this work?
  const { login } = useUser()
  expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

I have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-pond-9xww9) but it's erroring out about jest.mock not being a function so I don't know if it's very useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't get it to work without slightly change the source code a little bit.

First, I have to export the actual context

```
export { UserProvider, useUser, UserContext }
```

We can re create provider with a mocked `login` function and the following test will serve you purpose.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import Login from './Login'
import { UserProvider, useUser, UserContext } from './UserProvider'

it('should log a user in', () => {
  const login = jest.fn();
  const { getByText } = render(
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ login }}>
      <Login />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );

  const submitButton = getByText('Login');
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
});
```

It is entirely possible that this is not the best approach. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I see 2 more approaches here:

1. Inject `Context.Consumer` alongside your component under test. Then so you would be able to verify against it

```
  const contextCallback = jest.fn();
  const { getByText } = render(
    <UserProvider>
      <Login />
      <UserContext.Consumer>{contextCallback}</UserContext.Consumer>
    </UserProvider>
  );

  const submitButton = getByText('Login');
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  expect(contextCallback.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual({ 
    user: "John Doe"
  });
```

2. Mock calls behind `UserContext.Consumer`(let it be speculative `LoginAPI` call in `UserContext`)

```
jest.mock("../LoginAPI.js");
...
  const { getByText } = render(
    <UserProvider>
      <Login />
    </UserProvider>
  );

  const submitButton = getByText('Login');
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  expect(LoginAPI.login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

To me 2nd one is better while 1st rely on implementation details(context data's structure).

PS to 1st approach you may declare consumer component right in the test to avoid exporting `UserContext`:

```
function ContextHelper({ spy }) {
  const contextData = useUser();
  spy(contextData);
  return null;
}

...
  const contextCallback = jest.fn();
  const { getByText } = render(
    <UserProvider>
      <Login />
      <ContextHelper spy={contextCallback} />
    </UserProvider>
  );
```

But keep in mind that `spy` may be called more times that you'd expect.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on approach 2. Are you recommending I test on a method that is being called from a method inside context? e.g. I call `login` from the context but test that `loginAPI` is called (which would be called from `login`)?

Comment: Yes, right. It's not "testing in isolation" rather more "testing integration between component and context", but in 2nd case we would be _even more_ sure that while test passes everything works as we expect.

Answer (score -1):

contactUs.jsx

```
<div className="grey-box">
      <h3>{context.t("contact_us")}</h3>
      <p>{context.t("contact_us_description")}</p>
```

how to write test case for it in react it contain i18n-redux by using react-context