# Testing a component that uses context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write tests for the `Login` component of my app, and want to test that the user can enter email and password fields, then submit them.  There are two complications: it has a  to another component, and it uses context to import a function called `loginUser.` The first problem I solve by making a custom `renderWithRouter` function, but I can't solve the second problem because the component isn't able to consume the `loginUser` function outside of context.  I get this error: `Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]` because `loginUser` is undefined.  Any idea how I can solve this?  Here is `Login.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from 'context/authContext'
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

export const Login = (props: any) => {
  const { setUser, loginUser } = useAuth()
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>();
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<boolean>()
  const history = useHistory()

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginUser({
      email,
      password
    }).then((result: any) => {
      console.log(result)
      if (result.message === 'login error') {
        setErrors(true)
      } else {
        history.push('/dashboard/home')
      }
    })
  }

  return(
    <div className="login-wrapper">
      <h1>Please Log In</h1>
      <div className='form-wrapper'>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              isInvalid={errors ? true : false} 
              type="email" 
              placeholder="Enter email" 
              onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {errors ? 'either you don\'t have an account or the email and password do not match' : null}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
              umm..
            </Form.Text>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control 
              type="password" 
              placeholder="Password" 
              onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
          <div>
            <Link to='/register'>new user? click here to register</Link>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And Login.test.tsx:

```
  test("allows user to input their email", () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn();
    
    renderWithRouter(<Login />)
    const input = screen.getByLabelText("Email address")
    const pwd = screen.getByLabelText("Password")
    const button = screen.getByText("Submit")

    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "t@t.com"}})
    fireEvent.change(pwd, { target: { value: "123456"}})
    fireEvent.click(button)

    expect(onSubmit).toBeCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: Maybe just refactor it so you have a component that accepts a submit handler and an error prop?

Comment: @AndrewGillis thanks, could you explain a little more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test functions that are provided by context using jest and react-testing-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911684/how-can-i-test-functions-that-are-provided-by-context-using-jest-and-react-testi)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't run it but refactor to something like this and then test the `LoginForm` component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from 'context/authContext'
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

interface LoginFormProps {
  onSubmit: (email: string, password: string) => void;
  errors: boolean;
}
export const LoginForm: React.FC<LoginFormProps> = ({onSubmit, errors}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>();
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    onSubmit(email, password)
  }
  return(
    <div className="login-wrapper">
      <h1>Please Log In</h1>
      <div className='form-wrapper'>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              isInvalid={errors ? true : false} 
              type="email" 
              placeholder="Enter email" 
              onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {errors ? 'either you don\'t have an account or the email and password do not match' : null}
          </Form.Control.Feedback>
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
              umm..
            </Form.Text>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control 
              type="password" 
              placeholder="Password" 
              onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
          <div>
            <Link to='/register'>new user? click here to register</Link>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export const Login = (props: any) => {
  const { setUser, loginUser } = useAuth()
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const history = useHistory()

  const handleSubmit = (email, password) => {
    loginUser({
      email,
      password
    }).then((result: any) => {
      console.log(result)
      if (result.message === 'login error') {
        setErrors(true)
      } else {
        history.push('/dashboard/home')
      }
    })
  }

  return(
    <LoginForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} errors={errors} />
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks!  I did try this, but I think the fundamental problem remains: now when I call `fireEvent.click` on the new <LoginForm> component in my test, it throws an error because `loginUser` is not defined.

Comment: You’re passing a mocked function as the submit handler? It’s a bit confusing what part of your component you are trying to test.

Comment: apologies - really new to testing and I'm floundering.  I want to test that a user can enter their email, and password, and click on the submit button to submit that info.