# TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of undefined Testing Library + Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, chakra-ui

I created a component that has two buttons and their respective Chakra UI click events.

So I created a simple test and the idea is to generate a snapshot and then click events, but the following error occurs.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of undefined
```

In that case, should I make a mock or something? If yes, how would it be?

**Componente**

```
export const Buttons = ({children}: ButtonsProps) => {
  const {flag, setFlag} = useContext(Local.ContextCalculator)
  const {t} = useTranslation('comp_calculator')

  return (
    <>
      <C.Stack
        spacing={2}
        direction={'row'}
        align={'center'}
        justify={'center'}
      >
        <C.Button variant={'ghost'} size={'lg'} onClick={setFlag.off}>
          {t('buttons.clear')}
        </C.Button>

        <C.Button
          type={'submit'}
          colorScheme={'primary'}
          size={'lg'}
          onClick={setFlag.on}
        >
          {t('buttons.calculate')}
        </C.Button>
      </C.Stack>

      {flag && (
        <C.Stack spacing={8} data-testid={'result-table-calculator'}>
          {children}
        </C.Stack>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

**Test**

```
describe('Buttons', () => {
  const {Buttons} = jest.requireActual(
    '../../../src/components/calculator/Buttons'
  )

  afterEach(() => {
    Lib.resetAll()
  })

  it('renders as expect', async () => {
    const view = Lib.render(<Buttons />)
    expect(view.asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot()

    Lib.fireEvent.click(Lib.screen.getByText(/buttons\.calculate/i))
    await Lib.screen.findByTestId('result-table-calculator')

    Lib.fireEvent.click(Lib.screen.getByText(/buttons\.clear/i))
    expect(
      Lib.screen.queryByTestId('result-table-calculator')
    ).not.toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Comment: You need to wrap your component with the `ContextCalculator` provider in your test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test functions that are provided by context using jest and react-testing-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911684/how-can-i-test-functions-that-are-provided-by-context-using-jest-and-react-testi)